# Do you know how to parse a string to nullable<int>?

Tags: c#, int, nullable

I'm looking for a function where converts a string to a nullable int. But this one must returns an boolean value.

Comment: That's not much of a functional specification.  What string should produce null?  How exactly is the boolean involved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
    public int? NullableInt(string str)
    {
        int i;
        if (int.TryParse(str, out i))
            return i;
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
string str = "1234";
int number = 0;
int.TryParse(str, out number);
Nullable<int> result = new Nullable<int>(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
public static int? TryParse(string str)
{
    int result;
    if (Int32.TryParse(str, out result))
    {
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

If the parse fails, we return a null value, otherwise the value that was successfully parsed is returned.

Answer (score -1):

You can always parse the `string` to `int` and assign the result to an `int?` For example:

```
string myNumericString = "1234";
int? x = Int32.Parse(myNumericString);
```

You can also try:

```
int? x = null;
int result;
if (Int32.TryParse(myNumericString, out result) )
{
    x = result;
}

// Then you can check x.HasValue
```

Comment: `Int32.Parse(null)` raises `ArgumentNullException`. If successul it always returns `int`. So storing into `int?` has no effect at all.

Comment: Correct. The example assumes the happy path (i.e.`myNumericString` is `"1234"`). To be safe, you should use `Int32.TryParse(string, out int)`, which returns  `true` and assigns the parsed integer value to the out parameter if the parsing is successful.